# C# Fastest image resize routine for streaming video?

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I am trying to write a simple C# Windows App to display streaming video from a local USB webcam. I am using AForge.NET, FilterInfoCollection, VideoCaptureDevice etc to put video stream into a standard PictureBox. As is, it works fine. However, I need to downscale the videostream. When I try that, FPS drops significantly and becomes even lower as the app continues to run. My rescale routine is as follows (it aims to maintain aspect ratio and zoom in by preserving height):

```
public Image ResizeImage(Image img, int target_width, int height)
        {

            int width = (int)(height * img.Width / (float)img.Height);

            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(width, height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
            {
                g.DrawImage(img, (target_width - width)/2, 0, width, height);
            }

            return b;
        }
```

And it is called by:

```
private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                picVideo.Image = ResizeImage((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), picVideo.Width, picVideo.Height); // rescaled stream
                //picVideo.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(); // unscaled stream
            }));
            
        }
```

Setup code is this:

```
filterInfoCollection = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            videoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(filterInfoCollection[frmMain.Camera].MonikerString);

            videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += video_NewFrame;
            videoCaptureDevice.Start();
```

However, I have this old 3rd party EXE that runs fine and is able to rescale the same webcam videostream as I resize its window. So it looks like this rescaling routine is too slow.

So, is there a faster rescaling method? I basically need to achieve downscaling from FullHD to 1024*768. I don't really need this to be high-quality.

Answer (score 1):

Problem completely solved by adding

```
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
```

before g.DrawImage()

Comment: This just helped me using the same library, literally reduced cpu usage from 18% to 6%, crazy.

Thanks